# php pdf generation

Tags: php

In my project I have to give download my web page reports in pdf.

I am using ezpdf. But i have to do much of code again for pdf.

Is there any library which can generate pdf using html on web page.

I have tried with html2pdf. but it's not 100% ok. I have to give some chart (made by swiff chart  library) in download with report. here html2pdf nof working properly.

Is there any other library which can make my work easy.

Comment: You may want to check out the many other questions asked on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php to give you a head start.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both of your questions without a question mark: Yes.